# Gitlab CI job with specific user

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

I am trying to run Gitlab CI job of anchore engine to scan docker image.  The command in script section fails with error of `permission denied`. I found out the command requires `root` user permissions. Sudo is not installed in the docker image I'm using as `gitlab runner` and only non sudo user `anchore` is there in the docker container.

Below is the CI job for container scanning.

```
container_scan:
   stage: scan
   image:
    name: anchore/anchore-engine:latest
    entrypoint: ['']
   services:
    - name: anchore/engine-db-preload:latest
      alias: anchore-db

   variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
    ANCHORE_HOST_ID: "localhost"
    ANCHORE_ENDPOINT_HOSTNAME: "localhost"
    ANCHORE_CLI_USER: "admin"
    ANCHORE_CLI_PASS: "foobar"
    ANCHORE_CLI_SSL_VERIFY: "n"
    ANCHORE_FAIL_ON_POLICY: "true"
    ANCHORE_TIMEOUT: "500"

   script:
    - |
        curl -o /tmp/anchore_ci_tools.py https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anchore/ci-tools/master/scripts/anchore_ci_tools.py
        chmod +x /tmp/anchore_ci_tools.py
        ln -s /tmp/anchore_ci_tools.py /usr/local/bin/anchore_ci_tools
    - anchore_ci_tools --setup
    - anchore-cli registry add "$CI_REGISTRY" gitlab-ci-token "$CI_JOB_TOKEN" --skip-validate
    - anchore_ci_tools --analyze --report --image "$IMAGE_NAME" --timeout "$ANCHORE_TIMEOUT"
    - |
        if ; then
         anchore-cli evaluate check "$IMAGE_NAME"
        else
         set +o pipefail
         anchore-cli evaluate check "$IMAGE_NAME" | tee /dev/null
        fi

   artifacts:
    name: ${CI_JOB_NAME}-${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
    paths:
    - image-*-report.json
```

The CI job fails at `ln -s /tmp/anchore_ci_tools.py /usr/local/bin/anchore_ci_tools` in the script section.
I have tried to add user in the `entrypoint` section

```
  name: anchore/anchore-engine:latest
  entrypoint: ['bash', '-c', 'useradd myuser && exec su myuser -c bash']
```

but it did not allow to create a user. I have tried running the docker container in linux with `docker run -it --user=root anchore/anchore-engine:latest /bin/bash` and it run without any problem. How can I simulate the same in gitlab-ci job?

Comment: what if you change the image to use USER root

Comment: I did that and it works but I don't want to use custom image instead I want to fetch new and updated image every time the job is run

Comment: as far as I know, gitlab only allow the entrypoint to be changed. [This](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html) might help you

Comment: Any luck on this?  I am also facing this issue and am coming up empty.